# How to Access Function variables in Another Function Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

I have to access the variable msg_public of send_echo() in process_send(). Help me to do this.?

```
@dp.message(Form.msg)
async def send_echo(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        await message.send_copy(chat_id=message.chat.id)
    except TypeError:
        await message.reply(
            text='Try another type'
        )
    msg_public = message
    print(msg_public)
    await state.set_state(Form.sendMSG)
    await message.answer('Your message')
    return msg_public

#some code

@dp.message(Form.sendMSG)
async def process_send(message: **msg_public**, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    if str(current_time) == "10:45:00"
        await message.send_copy(chat_id=1232143545)
```

I try return and make variable global, but it did not help

Comment: Show how you tried to make it global and then tried to access it (as properly formatted code in the question). This should actually work.